# Merge Many json strings with python pandas inputs

Tags: python, json, serialization, pandas, concatenation

### Summary

I have created data objects that are comprised of (among other things), of `pandas` objects like `DataFrame`s and `Panel`s.  I'm looking to serialize these objects into `json`, and speed is a primary consideration.

### Example using a `pandas.Panel`

Say for instance I have a panel like so:

```
In [54]: panel = pandas.Panel( 
             numpy.random.randn(5, 100, 10), 
             items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
             major_axis = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start = '01/01/2000', 
                                               freq = 'b', 
                                               periods = 100
             ), 
             minor_axis = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'q', 'o']
          )
In [64]: panel
Out[64]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 5 (items) x 100 (major_axis) x 10 (minor_axis)
Items axis: a to e
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-05-19 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: z to o
```

And I'd like to turn this `panel` into flattened `json`

**NOTE:** I'm doing this with more complicated objects, but the overall logic of looping over keys and generating `json` data for each key is the same

I can write a quick and dirty `panel_to_json()` function like so:

```
def panel_to_json(panel):

    d = {'__type__' : 'panel'}
    for item in panel.items:
        tmp = panel.loc[item ,: , :].to_json()
        d[item] = eval(tmp)
    return json.dumps(d)

In [58]: tmp = panel_to_json(panel)
In [59]: tmp[:100]
Out[59]: '{"a": {"q": {"948931200000": -0.5586319118, "951955200000": 0.6820748888, "949363200000": -0.0153867'
```

Which gets me the correct result, the problem is the `eval` usage is **very** costly. For example, if I remove the `eval` and just deal with the smattering of `\\` that result from `panel_no_eval_to_json` function here:

```
def panel_no_eval_to_json(panel):
    d = {'__type__' : 'panel'}
    for item in panel.items:
        d[item] = panel.loc[item ,: , :].to_json()
    return json.dumps(d)

In [60]: tmp = panel_no_eval_to_json(panel)

In [61]: tmp[:100]
Out[61]: '{"a": "{\\"z\\":{\\"946857600000\\":1.0233515965,\\"946944000000\\":-1.1333560575,\\"947030400000\\":-0.0072'
```

The difference in speed is substantial, checkout their `%timeit` values!!:

```
In [62]: %timeit panel_no_eval_to_json(panel)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.55 ms per loop

In [63]: %timeit panel_to_json(panel)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.1 ms per loop
```

### End Goal

So my final goal would be to loop through the `Panel` (or my object, that has different keys / attributes, many of which are `Panel`'s and `DataFrame`s), and merge the `json` streams created from invoking `to_json()` into an aggregated `json` stream (which would actually be the flattening data representation of my data object) just as is performed by using the `panel_to_json` function above (the one **with** `eval`).

My key goals are:

1. Leverage existing `pandas to_json` functionality
2. Leverage speedups and existing libraries (I could write my own `json_stream_merger`, but clearly this has already been done, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the fastest way was to write a simple string `concat`-er.  Here were the two best solutions, (one provided by @Skorp)) and their respective `%timeit` times in graphical form

#### Method 1. String-Merge

```
def panel_to_json_string(panel):
    def __merge_stream(key, stream):
        return '"' + key + '"' + ': ' + stream + ', '

    try:
        stream = '{ "__type__": "panel", '
        for item in panel.items:
            stream += __merge_stream(item, panel.loc[item, :, :].to_json()) 

        # take out extra last comma
        stream = stream[:-2] 

        # add the final paren
        stream += '}'
    except:
        logging.exception('Panel Encoding did not work')
return stream
```

#### Method 2. Loads-Dumps

```
def panel_to_json_loads(panel):
    try:
        d = {'__type__' : 'panel'}

        for item in panel.items:
            d[item] = json.loads(panel.loc[item ,: , :].to_json())
        return json.dumps(d)
    except:
        logging.exception('Panel Encoding did not work')
```

#### Problem Setup

```
import timeit
import pandas
import numpy

setup = ("import strat_check.io as sio; import pandas; import numpy;" 
     "panel = pandas.Panel(numpy.random.randn(5, {0}, 4), "
     "items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], " 
     "major_axis = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start = '01/01/1990',"
                                        "freq = 's', "
                                        "periods = {0}), "
                                        "minor_axis = numpy.arange(4))")

vals = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]

d = {'string-merge': [], 
     'loads-dumps': []
     }

for n in vals:
    number = 10

d['string-merge'].append(
    timeit.timeit(stmt = 'panel_to_json_string(panel)', 
                  setup = setup.format(n), 
                  number = number)
)

d['loads-dumps'].append(
    timeit.timeit(stmt = 'sio.panel_to_json_loads(panel)', 
                  setup = setup.format(n), 
                  number = number)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if all you need to do is get rid of "\\" you could use
    `.str.strip("\\") #or`

```
`.str.replace("\\","") `
```

you should read up on string methods, vectorized string methods and regular expressions.  Here's pandas specific info link:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Skorp.  From my goals and objectives, you can see that I'm trying to "merge the json streams created from invoking `to_json()` into an aggregated json stream"

I was going to put that that simply using `replace("\\", "")` didn't accomplish what I was looking for, but I thought that was clear from my goals and objectives.  

Thanks for the response!

Comment: have you considered merging the dataframes and then "to_json" that frame? you could use pd.merge(masterdf, panel[item], how="outer").  Just a thought, I haven't worked with panels so not sure if the json representation would be accurate.  You could also try  pd.concat([masterdf, panel[item]], axis = 1, keys =[list(masterdf.columns, item) and then make that into a json

Comment: pd.concat([masterdf, panel[item]], axis = 1, keys =[list(masterdf.columns.values), item])

Comment: FYI @Skorp, `json_string.replace("\\", "")` does not result in a valid `json` string, FYI.  If you remove this answer, and then make your final `loads(df.to_json())` your answer, I'll give you an upvote because it's the second fastest solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered merging the dataframes and then "to_json" that frame? you could use pd.merge(masterdf, panel[item], how="outer"). Just a thought, I haven't worked with panels so not sure if the json representation would be accurate. You could also try using this in your loop.  You should also consider using the iteritems() method.

```
masterdf = pd.concat([masterdf, panel[item]], axis = 1, keys =[list(masterdf.columns.values), item]) and then make that into a json.
```

You may be even able to do something sexier like:

```
pd.concat([lamda x: x for panel.items], axis = 1, keys = list(panel.keys())).to_json
```

Comment: please see the **NOTE** Section "I'm doing this with more complicated objects, but the overall logic of looping over keys and generating json data for each key is the same," so the `(key, frame) / `(key, series)` / `(key, frame)` is part of the structure I'm working with (and therefore can't just `pandas.concat` everything

Comment: Have you tried using json.loads(tmp) instead of eval?