# large filesize difference between `pandas to_json` and `read_json`

Tags: python, json, serialization, pandas, celery

### Setup

The basis of this question is that I'm using [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [`rabbitmq`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) to create a distributed `HDFStore` messaging application that will pass `pandas DataFrame`s to distributed processes (and then write to `HDFStore`).  Because `json` is one of the [task serialization protocols](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results) accepted by `celery` the `to_json()` and `read_json()` functionality of `pandas` is perfect for accomplishing this.

So my application:

- hits and API and pulls down a `pandas.DataFrame`
- serializes the `DataFrame` using `to_json()`
- passes the serialized values to a `celery` worker
- re-creates the `DataFrame` on the other side using a `celery.group` method

### Problem

I found that when I was creating the HDFStore's, they were > 50x larger than if I just did a `for` loop and didn't serialize / de-serialize the object (using json).  So I've taken `celery` out of it and re-created it in a very simple function that re-creates the phenomenon:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import random


def test_store_size(n_dfs, f_path):
    wj_store = pandas.HDFStore(f_path + 'from_json.h5', mode = 'w')
    nj_store = pandas.HDFStore(f_path + 'from_dfrm.h5', mode = 'w')

    ticks = []

    for i in numpy.arange(n_dfs):

        tag = _rnd_letters(5)
        print "working on " + str(i)

        index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(
                start = '01/01/2000', 
                periods = 1000, 
                freq = 'b'
        )

        df = pandas.DataFrame(
                numpy.random.rand(len(index), 3), 
                columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                index = index
        )

        nj_store[tag] = df

        stream = df.to_json(
                orient = 'index', 
                date_format = 'iso',
        )

        #stream = df.to_json(orient = 'values')
        wj_df = pandas.read_json(
                stream, 
                typ = 'frame', 
                orient = 'index', 
                dtype = _dtype_cols(df)
        )

        #wj_df = pandas.read_json(stream, convert_dates = False, orient = 'values')
        wj_store[tag] = wj_df

    wj_store.close()
    nj_store.close()

def _rnd_letters(n_letters):
    """Make random tags for the DataFrames"""
    s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [random.choice(s) for i in numpy.arange(n_letters)])

def _dtype_cols(df):
    """map the types for dytpes"""
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    return dict([(col, numpy.float) for col in cols])
```

So if you run the following function:

```
In [1]: test_store_size(n_dfs = 10, f_path = '/Users/benjamingross/Desktop/tq-')
```

The following is the disparity between the `HDFStore`s:

[image: size-diff]

So 21.4 MB is 59x greater than 365 KB!!!  I'm dealing with 1,000s of `DataFrame`s so what seems like very little space on my hard drive (400MB) is turning out to be 24 GB, which is now a "Big Data" issue (and shouldn't be).

Any help getting serialization using `to_json` and `read_json` to "behave" (i.e. be the same size before and after serialization) would be greatly appreciated.

### What I've Tried

I've tried all the different parameters in `to_json / read_json`, including `orient = values` which **almost works**, but then I need to serialize the `index` and `columns`, which, when [re-created in very creative ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078118/merge-many-json-strings-with-python-pandas-inputs) **still** ends up being 60x of the original size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look back through the output from your program, you probably had a message like this:

```
In [7]: wj_df.to_hdf('test.h5', 'key')
PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->unicode,key->axis0] [items->None]
```

It's not particularly obvious, but your column names are being read back as unicode rather than a python string - which PyTables doesn't handle well in python2, so it falls back to pickling.  A relatively easy workaround would be to cast the column as a string, like this.

```
wj_df.columns = wj_df.columns.astype(str)
```

There's an issue on GitHub for this problem below.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5743

Comment: Weird thing I wasn't getting those warnings, but I **was** getting them in my distributed `celery` application.  

Thanks so much for the insight, quick fix, and now same size read / write!!